# str_replace specific value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, str-replace

I would like to replace the `,` with `.` in some Keys like `[Price]` for instance.

Given this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product line] => Misc
            [Seller] => aaa.com
            [Tracking ID] => bbbb
            [Date shipped] => October 23, 2015
            [Price] => 60,43
            [Referral fee rate] => 3,00%                
            [Quantity] => 2
            [Revenue] => 120,86
            [Earnings] => 3,62
            [Sub Tag] => xxxx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Product line] => Misc
            [Seller] => aaaa.com
            [Tracking ID] => bbbb
            [Date shipped] => October 23, 2015
            [Price] => 9,34
            [Referral fee rate] => 6,96%                
            [Quantity] => 1
            [Revenue] => 9,34
            [Earnings] => 0,65
            [Sub Tag] => xxxx
        )
)
```

And the following function:

```
function str_replace_specific_value($sSearch, $sReplace, &$aSubject){
    foreach($aSubject as $sKey => $uknValue) {
        if(is_array($uknValue)) {
            foreach($sKey as $fKey => $fuknValue) {
                $uknValue['Price'] = str_replace($sSearch, $sReplace, $fuknValue);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Can someone help me please? I tried a couple of things but can't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, can you take a look at the function I just posted? I'm close, but something's still not right

Comment: Instead of all that loops, why not use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive)? (check the comments to see how to change the array in the callback function)

Comment: As a side-note, you should really return the modified array from your function instead of sending the original by reference; your current method makes testing and troubleshooting very hard.

Comment: @Uchiha I tried this but it doesn't work, the output is still comma not dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through each element of associative array using `array_walk_recursive` function.

Here `$result` is your input array.

```
array_walk_recursive($result, 'replacer');

/**
 * Replace comma with dot from 'Price' element of associative array.
 * This function call recursively
 *
 * @access public
 *
 * @param string|int|null $item
 * @param string $key
 * @return void
 */
public function replacer(& $item, $key)
{
    if ($key == 'Price') {
        $item = str_replace(",", ".", $item);
    }
}
```

`var_dump($result)` to check the output after replacing `,` with `.`

Answer (score 1):

Change the main array, like this:

```
function str_replace_specific_value($sSearch, $sReplace, &$aSubject){
    foreach($aSubject as $key => $sub_array) {
        if(is_array($sub_array)) {
            foreach($sub_array as $sub_key => $sub_value) {
                $sSubject[$key][$sub_key] = str_replace($sSearch, $sReplace, $sub_value);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

In casu you wanted to do only on a set of keys, you would need to declare those keys and use this other function:

```
$keys_to_be_replaced = ['price','whatever'];

function str_replace_specific_value($sSearch, $sReplace, &$aSubject, $keys_to_be_replaced){
    foreach($aSubject as $key => $sub_array) {
        if(is_array($sub_array)) {
            foreach($sub_array as $sub_key => $sub_value) {
                if(in_array($sub_key,$keys_to_be_replaced))
                  $sSubject[$key][$sub_key] = str_replace($sSearch, $sReplace, $sub_value);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$arr[0] = array("price" => "60,53");
$arr[1] = array("price" => "9,34");

foreach ($arr AS $key => $value) {
   $arr[$key]["price"] = str_replace(",", ".", $arr[$key]["price"]);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 60.53
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 9.34
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate

```
array_walk_recursive($r, function (your args){
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Via [array_walk_recursive](https://%20https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) if you want to change the values of an existing multi-dimensional array you need to specify the first argument of the callback as a reference by preceding the variable with an ampersand (&)

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$item, $key){
            
    if( $key == 'Price' ){
                
        $item = str_replace(',','.',$item);
    }
});
```